# stat & S_IFREG in C++

Tags: c++, unix

```
void fun1(char *fl){
//flNamep : stores the path of our directory
DIR *dip;   
struct dirent *dit;
dip = opendir(fl);
if (dip==NULL) {cerr<<"Error\n";exit(-1);}  

while ((dit=readdir(dip)))
 {  
    string trun = (dit->d_name);
    struct stat buff;       
    stat(dit->d_name, &buff); 

    if  (((buff.st_mode & S_IFREG)==S_IFREG)) 
        {cout<<"File"<<endl;}
    else if (((buff.st_mode & S_IFDIR)==S_IFDIR)) 
        {cout<<"Dir"<<endl;} 
     }
closedir(dip);
}
```

Code does not differentiate in dir and files. Am i missing something? I can not use Boost or any other STL. only C Posix Supported files. Need to know were i am wrong.

Updated code as per answer

```
    DIR *dip;   
struct dirent *dit;
dip = opendir(flNamep);
if (dip==NULL) {cerr<<"Err\n";exit(-1);}                            

while ((dit=readdir(dip)))
 {  
    string trun = (dit->d_name);
    string fullpath = flNamep;
    fullpath+='/';
    fullpath+=trun;

    if((trun==".") || (trun=="..")) {cout<<"";}         
    else
    {       
    struct stat buff;               

    stat(dit->d_name, &buff);       
        if (((buff.st_mode & S_IFDIR)==S_IFDIR)) 
        {cout<<"Dir"<<endl;} 
        else
        {cout<<"File"<<endl;}

    }
```

Comment: Consider using `S_ISREG(buff.st_mode)` and `S_ISDIR(buff.st_mode)`.  Not that it affects the '_unchecked `stat()`_' problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the `stat` actually fails with `ENOENT` (no such file) so `buff` doesn't contain anything useful.

```
stat(dit->d_name, &buff); /* dirent.d_name is just the name, not the full path */
```

You probably want to concatenate `fl, "/", d_name`. But first of all, check the value returned by `stat`.

Comment: cout<<" "<<dit->d_name<<" "<<(buff.st_mode & S_IFDIR) << " " <<buff.st_mode<< endl;  shows this:
 .. 16384 16833
 dir1 16384 16833
 dir2 16384 16833
 dir3 16384 16833
 file1 16384 16833
 file2 16384 16833

Comment: @typedef1 Try to cout the value returned by `stat` :-)

Comment: it is -1 in all Cases .. except first where it is 0.

Comment: @typedef1 Which means you have to prefix the filename with the path.

Comment: Can you Hint me How to do it?

Comment: i have created a string that contains the current file's full path by prepanding fl/ to it. But now while using stat, it shows an error :  : error: cannot convert 'std::string' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int stat(const char*, stat*)

Comment: @typedef1: there is already a hint in the third line of the answer!

Comment: str::string provides a method `c_str()`; use it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i used it. but it converts the parameter into a typeid().name as PKc which is different from A_c which is desired.